# How does 'read_stream' permission affect a posts query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I ran this query on a local business's page from inside the graph api explorer:

19292868552?fields=posts.limit(10).fields(comments.fields(id,created_time,from,message)) to print the last 10 posts with their comments.

I found that I could read 'most' of the 10 posts with the default permissions, but when I reran using a token with the 'read_stream' permission added I could see several more than before (probably all 10 - I didn't count them).  However, I couldn't figure out WHY.  The posts were very similar.  Most of the ones that weren't available at first were shared photos with comments, but there were other shared photos that I could see.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The read_stream permission gives access to more than just the user's own posts; it gives you access to their entire news feed.

> Provides access to all the posts in the user's News Feed and enables
>   your application to perform searches against the user's News Feed

source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: Venting === Lamest permission ever made by facebook. why should that option prevent us from viewing a simple link pasted into a group. It's not a shared link or anything special, Just a simple link to a website and it won't show in the feed. It's my group and my post? wth... http://feedthemsocial.com/facebook-group-feed-demo/